Is a pseudo-effective divisor on a rational surface numerically effective?
Let $D$ be a pseudo-effective $\mathbb{R}$-divisor on a rational surface. Can we find an example that the numerical class of $D$ contains no effective divisor?

"Numerically effective class" and "numerical class of effective divisor" are not the same things. It is better to change the title of your question in accordance with the question itself.

I think you are asking whether the Mori cone NE(X) on a surface X is closed. A ruled surface counterexample due to Mumford is given  in Lazarsfeld's Positivity in Algebraic Geometry I, Example 1.5.1.

@EvgenyShinder I think the question is a bit different: is the closed $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$-cone of pseudoeffective divisors  (i.e., the closure of the big cone) spanned by effective divisors?

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn Mumford's example is a P1-bundle over a curve; producing non-effective divisor rely producing a certain stable certain rank 2 bundle on C. Anyway, P1-bundles which are rational must be Hirzebruch surfaces, hence toric, so all cones are rational polyhedral.

Nagata's famous counterexample to Hilbert's 14th problem seems to be what you are after.
In this example, Nagata considers the blow-up $X$ of $P^2$ at 16 very general points $p_1,\ldots,p_{16}$. So $X$ is a smooth rational surface with Picard group $\mathbb{Z}^{17}$. If $H$ denotes the pullback of the hyperplane class in $P^2$, and $E_1,\ldots,E_{16}$ denote the exceptional divisors, then the class
$$
D=4H-E_1-\ldots-E_{16}
$$is nef, hence pseudoeffective. Indeed, when the 16 points are a complete intersection of two degree 4 curves $V(F)$ and $V(G)$, it is easy to see that $D\cdot C\ge 0$ for every curve $C$, by considering the linear system of curves $\{sF+tG=0\}$ for varying $s$ and $t$. Therefore, by a specialization argument, the class $D$ remains nef on the very general blow-up as well.
However, Nagata showed, using a similar specialization argument, that no multiple of $D$ is effective.
I believe this is explained in the paper
M. Nagata. On the fourteenth problem of Hilbert. Proc. ICM Edinburgh (1958),
459–462.
